# Incorrect result returned after reading binary file (int value)

Tags: c

I try to read value from binary file. I know offset (3201) and use it.

Example code:

```
FILE *bin_file;
int *job_id_buffer; 

bin_file = fopen("sample.sgy", "rb");

if (bin_file == NULL)
{
// ... skipped ... 
}

fseek(bin_file, 3201, SEEK_SET);

job_id_buffer = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

fread(job_id_buffer, sizeof(int), 1, bin_file);

printf("%d\n", (int)job_id_buffer[0]);

fclose(bin_file);
```

Looks like I don't know how to read value correctly.

But problem is that when I get result, the value is **993024**, while I 100% know that correct value is **9999**.

Could you, please, help me to understand what I do incorrectly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 9999 = 0x0000**270F**, 993024 = 0x00**0F27**00

Comment: You seem to be off by one byte, and have your byte order wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the file endianness is the same as the program's?

Comment: @stark I'm sure it's not.

Comment: firstly @JimmyB you are right! The problem was in 1 byte, I used 3201 offset instead of 3200. Thank you! 
Now I've got a value - 254214144 (Little endian) - if convert it to Big Endian is is **9999**.
P.S. I would mark you answer as correct but I don't know how to it with your comment ^(

Comment: I don't understand why people keep downvoting this question :-\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick look at the values you got:

Expected: 9999 = 0x0000**270F**

Received: 993024 = 0x00**0F27**00

From this we can see two things:

1. `0F27` is `270F` with swapped bytes. Apparently, the byte order (endiannes) inside the file is not the same as that in memory;
2. If only the byte order was swapped, you would be getting `0x0F270000` from the file, but the value seems to be shifted by one byte.

This can mean one of two things, depending on the endianness of the file:

If the file is little-endian (and the CPU is big-endian), you should be seeking to offset `3202` instead of `3201`.

If the file is big-endian (and the CPU is little-endian), you should be seeking to offset `3200` instead of `3201`.

So, check the endianness of the file and correct your offset; then, convert the data read from the endianness of the file to the endianness of your CPU (reverse the bytes in this case) to get the correct value.

To create code that is correct on any CPU, you may be able to use [`be32toh()`, or `le32toh()`,](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/endian.3.html) to convert big-endian, or little-endian respectively, file data to the right CPU endianness.